# Combine ORDER BY and GROUP BY and a counter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use this SQL query to get customer order lines from an imported CSV file

```
select * from tblorderlines
where ordernr in (select ordernr from tblorderlines where linetype = 'H')
order by ordernr
```

and get this result

```
id      date         ordernr   customer     customerid  
7608    2020-06-15   77654     Customer 1   1111
7609    2020-06-15   77655     Customer 2   2222
7610    2020-06-16   77656     Customer 3   3333
7611    2020-06-16   77657     Customer 1   1111
7612    2020-06-16   77658     Customer 4   4444
```

Now I would like to produce 2 different results, where one, in addition to *order by `ordernr`* also group them by their `customerid`

```
id      date         ordernr   customer     customerid  
7608    2020-06-15   77654     Customer 1   1111
7611    2020-06-16   77657     Customer 1   1111
7609    2020-06-15   77655     Customer 2   2222
7610    2020-06-16   77656     Customer 3   3333
7612    2020-06-16   77658     Customer 4   4444
```

and another where I get a *counter (the `cnt` column)* with how many times a `customer`/`customerid` occurs

```
id      date         ordernr   customer     customerid   cnt
7608    2020-06-15   77654     Customer 1   1111         2
7609    2020-06-15   77655     Customer 2   2222         1
7610    2020-06-16   77656     Customer 3   3333         1
7611    2020-06-16   77657     Customer 1   1111         2
7612    2020-06-16   77658     Customer 4   4444         1
```

---

I've tried several `join` and `group by` solutions, though my SQL skills aren't good enough to get me these results.

Comment: Are all these columns in single table like Customer and cutomerID ?is ID autoincreament ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh -- Yes, and yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just order by `customer` prior to `ordernr` to group the values, and use `COUNT` as a window function to get the count of each `customerid`. Combining both in one query (and considering your initial query as a view):

```
SELECT *,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customerid) AS cnt
FROM tblorderview
ORDER BY customer, ordernr
```

Output (based on the results of your original query):

```
id      date        ordernr     customer    customerid  cnt
7608    2020-06-15  77654       Customer 1  1111        2
7611    2020-06-16  77657       Customer 1  1111        2
7609    2020-06-15  77655       Customer 2  2222        1
7610    2020-06-16  77656       Customer 3  3333        1
7612    2020-06-16  77658       Customer 4  4444        1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04d9a2/1)

**Update**

Based on discussion in comments, the ordering actually needs to be done so that all a customers orders are grouped together and sorted into the list based on the minimum order number for that customer. This can be done with this query:

```
SELECT *,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customerid) AS cnt
FROM tblorderview
ORDER BY MIN(ordernr) OVER (PARTITION BY customerid),
         ordernr
```

Output (for the expanded demo):

```
id      date        ordernr     customer    customerid  cnt
7608    2020-06-15  77654       Customer 8  8888        1
7609    2020-06-15  77655       Customer 7  7777        2
7615    2020-06-17  77661       Customer 7  7777        2
7610    2020-06-16  77656       Customer 6  6666        1
7611    2020-06-16  77657       Customer 5  5555        1
7612    2020-06-16  77658       Customer 4  4444        2
7617    2020-06-18  77663       Customer 4  4444        2
7613    2020-06-17  77659       Customer 3  3333        1
7614    2020-06-17  77660       Customer 2  2222        1
7616    2020-06-18  77662       Customer 1  1111        1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7519f/3)

Comment: Thanks. Are there any possibilities to do `ORDER BY ordernr` and then group them by their `customerid`?

Comment: @Ason if you group by the customer id, you will only get 4 rows in the output (there would only be 1 row for `customerid` 1111). In addition, you would then need to use aggregation or window functions over the other columns to avoid group by errors. What are you trying to achieve with the group by? If you just want the last output data in your question, just remove `customer` from the `ORDER BY`. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04d9a2/2

Comment: The snippet here is part of a warehouse solution, and when the customer goes through its backorders, they want to know if a given customer has more than one, and since the list holds +100 items, it would be a lot easier to have them grouped.

Comment: @Ason it can definitely be done, if you can just let me know what you would like the output to look like, I'm sure I could modify the query as required.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will create a couple of "sqlfiddle demos" to show what I am looking for. Let you know when I'm done with that.

Comment: [This first one](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7519f/1) becomes wrong as it orders them by `customerid, ordernr` and it should be ordered by `ordernr` first. -- [This second one](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7519f/2) orders them correct but they aren't grouped together. -- [This third](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/67eb2/1) is how I want, ordered by `ordernr` and then grouped, and I added a fake _fordeorder_ column to force the output.

Comment: @Ason I see what you mean - the examples make it clear. I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: @Ason try this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7519f/3

Comment: Again, thank your very much. Could you update your answer with that too, as it is exactly what I were looking for, and a short explanation how the `ORDER BY` part actual works. And as soon as I can, I will start/award a bounty for your efforts.

Comment: @Ason I'm glad that was what you were looking for. Thanks for the offer, but there's really no need for a bounty, I should have put more effort into figuring out what you actually wanted to begin with.

Comment: Soon you'll have your "Overflow cup" :) ... and again thanks. The awarded bounty reflects what the value of your answer meant to me, and it saved me lots of time.

Comment: @Ason I just saw what you did!!! You really didn't have to but I am truly appreciative and glad that this answer was so useful to you.